# Programming language for building up mathematical constructs from axioms with an OO style?

Tags: programming-languages, symbolic-math

Is Haskell capable of this? Or some other functional language?

Please forgive me if I make a hash of describing this....

Suppose I wanted to build up a mathematical construct of a group. So if I wanted to describe a mathematical group I would need to have the basic types of a set and a binary operation (Perhaps I have to define a binary operation too?).

Now if I try and create a group using the set of negative numbers and multiplication, it should fail because this group does not meet the axiomatic requirement of closure. So that rule of groups needs to be specified somehow within the group object.

Now obviously we can use our group object to build other math Objects, and go about building a whole range of mathematical constructs.

This paper seems to describe what I am looking for, they mention a Maple package but its been 10 years since publication:  http://www.springerlink.com/content/y387p318l9438023/

Any ideas where I can find such an environment?

I am not looking for a proof checker, more an interactive environment for exploring mathematics.

Edit: Surely the early efforts at theorem proving must have required a language like I have described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog is good for handling axioms. There is a open source object-oriented extension of prolog at sourceforge.net:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oopl/

Comment: Ok this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type system of the [Fortress Programming Language](https://ProjectFortress.Sun.Com/) works in some way similar to what you describe. It uses an Object-Oriented Type System with Generic Traits to describe e.g. Algebraic Properties of Operators (like Associativity, Commutativity, Distributivity, Identity, Symmetry, One-Element, Zero-Element and so on). It needs to know all these in order to automatically distribute computations across nodes in a cluster.

Comment: Ok this looks pretty good. It is obviously quite young though. I'll check it out.